# Terraform add aws iam statement conditionally

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using following terraform data source to add resource policy to S3 bucket -

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "inbound_bucket_policy" { 
  statement {
    sid    = "Set permissions for objects"
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      identifiers = ["${var.inbound_source_replication_role_arn}"]
      type        = "AWS"
    }
    actions = [
      "s3:ReplicateObject",
      "s3:ReplicateDelete",
      "s3:ReplicateTags"
    ]
    resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.inbound_bucket.arn}/*"]
  }

  statement {
    sid    = "Set permissions on bucket"
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      identifiers = ["${var.inbound_source_replication_role_arn}"]
      type        = "AWS"
    }
    actions   = ["s3:List*", "s3:GetBucketVersioning", "s3:PutBucketVersioning"]
    resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.inbound_bucket.arn}"]
  }

}
```

There may be more statements coming in the future. What we need is to control each statement block conditionally. We maintain env variable which holds the value of AWS env terraform is deploying. We want if the var.env == "prd" then certain statements should not be created. We know the **dynamic _block** approach but the argument values are different for each statement so it may not be feasible to use that. Is there any different approach to handle this ?
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Make each `statement` a separate `dynamic` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the policies up:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "source_one" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["ec2:*"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }

  statement {
    sid = "UniqueSidOne"

    actions   = ["s3:*"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "source_two" {
  statement {
    sid = "UniqueSidTwo"

    actions   = ["iam:*"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }

  statement {
    actions   = ["lambda:*"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}
```

and then you can control how those are combined, e.g. with a ternary condition:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "combined" {
  source_policy_documents = var.env == "prd" ? [data.aws_iam_policy_document.source_one.json, data.aws_iam_policy_document.source_one.json] : [data.aws_iam_policy_document.source_one.json]
}
```

so if `var.env` is equal to `prd`, then `data.aws_iam_policy_document.combined.json` will contain both policies, otherwise it will contain only the first one.

Alternatively, if you have several possible environments, then you could use the [lookup](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/lookup) function:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "combined" {
  source_policy_documents = lookup({
    "dev"     = [data.aws_iam_policy_document.source_one.json]
    "prd"     = [data.aws_iam_policy_document.source_one.json, data.aws_iam_policy_document.source_two.json]
  }, var.env, [])
}
```